# react-native static class properties

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I had this working in a react-native app, but I feel I had to do some stuff with babel and I can't remember what it was. For whatever reason this is not working, it's saying cannot read property `CONSTANT_1` of `undefined`.

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

    static MyClassProp = {
       CONSTANT_1: 1,
       CONSTANT_2: 2
    };

    static defaultProps = {
       prop1: Main.MyClassProp.CONSTANT_1
    };

    ...

}
```

Can anybody tell me if I'm supposed to include something in a `.babelrc` or `package.json` to get this to compile correctly?

Comment: Are you using redux at all?

Comment: @nonsequiter - no.

Comment: Do you have your application under version control, you could check previous commits to see where the change happened? At this moment, I would need a lot more information to help solve the problem, such as current babel version and configs set in `package.json` or `.babelrc`.

Comment: `.babelrc` and `package.json` are the same was what comes with a fresh `react-native init` nowadays (react-native v 0.51.0)

Comment: @Adam could you post your `.babelrc`?